# Vertically align floating DIVs

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-float

I have a portion of a website I am creating that is as follows:

```
<div id="topbar">
    <div id="topbar_left">
        <form action="Search" method="POST">
            <label for="searchtext">Find Products: </label><input type="text" name="searchtext" id="searchtext" size="30" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="topbar_right">
        You are logged in as Username &bull; <a href="LogOut">Log Out</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I would like for the text in **topbar_right** to be vertically centered to that in **topbar_left**. However, **topbar_right** doesn't always contain text, it also can also contain a small form, which displays fine because it is the same height as the one on the left.

Here is my current CSS:

```
#topbar {
    background-color: #5a87bf;
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
#topbar_left {
    float: left;
}
#topbar_right {
    float: right;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

What is the best way to go about achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally find that setting the line-height helps here.
something like this might work:

```
#topbar_left, #topbar_right {
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

You can also try fiddling around with the **vertical-align** CSS property. Read [this article](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) about how to use it properly

good luck

Comment: Thanks, i've read the article previously and have tried to make it work using vertical-align but it doesn't seem to help. In regards to line-height, i'd prefer not to set an explicit height, but if there's no other way to do it then I might so that.